# What's the change of variables theorem in terms of pullback?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In multivariable calculus, how do you restate the change of variable theorem (the one that has Jacobian matrix in it) in terms of pullback and differential forms? and, if such restatement exists, is it easy to use in real life? (easy to use means you can use it to calculate some specific problems)

[PS: If you give an answer, I cannot accept it, because I don't have enough knowledge to verify it.]

Comment: Usually you write that $\int_{\gamma}\; d\omega = \int_{\alpha^{-1} \circ \gamma}\; \alpha^{*}(d\omega) = \int_{\alpha^{-1} \circ \gamma}\; d(\omega \circ \alpha)$. For more details, I recommend either Spivak's or Munkres' book on manifolds.